# How to adapt the height of a <div> in BootStrap ScrollSpy?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website with bootstrap 3 scrollspy. I want each div to fit the size of the screen, but I can't make it work...how can I do this?
After this, second question: how can I make the first div not going behind the navbar fixed on top? Thank you!

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Il Luculliano</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 3</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add scrollspy to <body>
  $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  // End if
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
body {
      position: relative; 
      height: 100%;
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add scrollspy to <body>
  $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  // End if
  });
});
```

```css
html,body {
      position: relative; 
      height: 100%;
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Il Luculliano</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 3</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
      <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: '*Second question: how can I make the first div not going behind the navbar fixed on top?*', First div is still behind the navigation. Add padding to body to shift it down